# Windows Photo Gallery not showing my photos

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-photo-gallery

I've fired up Windows Photo Gallery, right-clicked on the Pictures node, selected `Manage Pictures library` and added a bunch of network folders (from mapped drives) with JPGs and PNGs.

Unfortunately, nothing is happening - these photos are not showing up in the Photo Gallery.

Am I missing something simple?  Does it not support network drives?

Answer (score -2):

It should work but only if the images are in .bmp format. This is the only format my windows photo gallery in Vista Home Premium shows.
It is made by Microsoft so it is not surprising.